# Estadística bayesiana, percentiles 5 % y 95 % en la distribución beta con r y R2OPENBUGS

Tags: r

Necesito obtener los percentiles 5 % y 95% en la salida de la instrucción bugs en R2openBUGS, para poder hacer un contraste de hipótesis unilateral, con un intervalo de credibilidad bayesiano del 95%. Les adjunto el código en r y openBUGS. El problema es que no encuentro la instrucción dentro de Bugs en R2openBUGS para poder indicar o setear más percentiles o cuantiles.
¿Pueden ustedes por favor ayudarme en esta tarea? Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
        library("R2OpenBUGS") 
        library("coda") 
        library("lattice")

        n4 = 10000  
        n5 = 1000
        n6 = 1
        n7 = 1
        N= 10
        r = 8
        a = 1
        b = 1

        mod<-"mbp2022.txt"

        data <- list( N = N,
              r = r,
              a = a,
              b = b          
        )
        sink(mod)
        cat("
       
        model{

       pi1 ~ dbeta(a,b)    
       r ~ dbin(pi1, N)

      }

      ",fill=TRUE) 
      sink()

      modelfile <- mod


      vars <-list("pi1")

      inits <-function(){list(pi1=0.5)} 

 

      out <-bugs(
  
      model.file=file.path(modelfile),
  
      data=data,
  
      inits=inits,
  
      parameters.to.save=vars, 
   
      n.iter=n4, 
      n.burnin=n5, 
      n.chains=n6,
      n.thin=n7,
      summary.only = F,
      debug=F, 
      DIC=F, 
      working.directory = getwd(),
  
      )
      cat("\n")  
      print (out, digits = 03)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para encontrar los percentiles se puede utilizar la función `quantile` pero depende de qué data quieras. No conozco en detalle la salida de openBugs pero supón que la salida `out$sims.matrix` es una matriz con iteraciones en filas y variables simuladas en columnas y la segunda columna es la variable buscada:

```
quantile(out$sims.matrix[,2],c(0.05,0.95))
```

devuelve los cuantiles 5% y 95%

Comment: La solución aportada es buena, funciona solo cuando tengo más de 1 variable, para cada fila la salida es correcta.  Ahora, por ejemplo la salida de la variable out 
`(print (out, digits = 03) 
        
         mean    sd   2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5%
pi1 0.748 0.121  0.481 0.674 0.765 0.841 0.928
di  0.248 0.121 -0.019 0.174 0.265 0.341 0.428
pp  0.033 0.180  0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000
`
Lo que necesito es el intervalo %5 y 95% de las tres filas o variables al mismo tiempo. He intentado manejando índices pero no lo logro.

Comment: Es que lo que me estás mostrando ya son cuantiles calculados, y no incluyen el 5% y el 95%. ¿algún parámetro para incluir esos cuantiles en BUGS? ¿Esto que imprimes es un resumen o el detalle de la variable? ¿que te muestra la salida de `dput(out)`?

Comment: Exacto. No encuentro ningún parámetro en BUGS para añadir esos %, y la salida de  `dput(out)` no la puedo poner aquí porque es demasiado larga

Comment: Si out es un vector (p.e. `unclass(out)`) basta con `quantile(unclass(out),c(0.05,0.95))`, pero no lo se.

Comment: `quantile(unclass(out),c(0.05,0.95))` me da error `Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic`
y ` out$sims.list
$pi1
[1] 0.5793 0.6720 0.8380 0.5790
`es la salida de
`out$sims.list`

Comment: `quantile(out$sims.list$pi1 ,c(0.05,0.95))` quizá. Chequea tambien el `length(out$sims.list$pi1)` para saber si son muestras.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140438/discussion-between-toto28-and-ric-villalba).